# Rellich-Kondrachov variant for compact manifold with piecewise $C^1$ boundary?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem) Wikipedia article, the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem says that whenever $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact manifold with $C^1$ boundary then
$W^{k,p}(M)$ embeds compactly in $W^{\ell,q}(M)$ if $k>\ell$ and $k-n/p>\ell-n/q$. Does a similar result follow for manifolds with piecewise $C^1$ boundary such as a rectangle?

Comment: For a rectangle, or a domain in Euclidean space with piecewise smooth boundary, clearly you can quote theorems from Adams book, which is probably still the standard reference. But that doesn't quite answer your question.

Comment: Bounded Lipschitz domains should be fine since you have a bounded universal extension operator in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quote the following remark from "Aubin, Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds. Monge-Ampère Equations":

> **2.35 Remark.** We have given only the main results concerning the theorems of Sobolev and Kondrakov. These theorems are proved for the compact manifolds with Lipschitzian boundary in Aubin [17]..

> [17] Aubin T.-Espaces de Sobolev sur les varietes Riemanniennes. Bull. Sc. Math. 100,
> (1976) 149-173.